# Creating form with values from uploaded files

Tags: javascript, html, forms

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/240t5kyj/)

I have a form you can upload images to like this,

```
 <form id="upload" method="post" action="actions/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="drop">
                Drop Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>

            <form onSubmit="addTags();return false;">
            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Add Tags" class="submit" id="login"/>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

After the images are uploaded they are listed in the form area to show the file names that were uploaded successfully. The jquery handles this like this,

```
  tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name);
```

Notice the file names are added the HTML as `<li> file name </li>`

Once this is done I would like the user to have the ability to click in to an input field and input comma separated tags that describe each image.

I have a function built called `addTags()`

Instead of just listing the file names how can I make it so it crates an input field with the name value of each input being the filename allowing me to easily enter the data to the database?

I have my form calling the addTags() function built around the area the file names are being listed but I cannot figure how to make it so its input fields being listed instead of just the names, this form I am speaking of looks like this,

```
<form onSubmit="addTags();return false;">
            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Add Tags" class="submit" id="login"/>
                    </form>
```

Full Javascript looks like this,

```
$(function(){

    var ul = $('#upload ul'); 

    $('#drop a').click(function(){
        // Simulate a click on the file input button
        // to show the file browser dialog
        $(this).parent().find('input').click();
    });

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
    $('#upload').fileupload({

        // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
        dropZone: $('#drop'),

        // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
        // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
        add: function (e, data) {

             var tpl = $('<li class="working uploaded"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

        // Append the file name and file size      
            tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name);

            // Add the HTML to the UL element
            data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

            // Initialize the knob plugin
            tpl.find('input').knob();

            // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
            tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                    jqXHR.abort();
                }

                tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                    tpl.remove();
                });

            });

            // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
            var jqXHR = data.submit();
        },

        progress: function(e, data){

            // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

            // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
            // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
            data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

            if(progress == 100){
                data.context.removeClass('working');
            }
        },

        fail:function(e, data){
            // Something has gone wrong!
            data.context.addClass('error');
        }

    });


    // Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
    $(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Helper function that formats the file sizes
    function formatFileSize(bytes) {
        if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
            return '';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
        }

        if (bytes >= 1000000) {
            return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }

        return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
    }

});
```

Please show me what to alter to make input fields with the filename as the name value for each input field which would hold the tags.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about keeping `input` fields next to file name and each input will contain tag of that image!

Comment: Man, my weakest area is JS. Please help me make this work. I have built this whole program in a few weeks and I am very close to launch but this one problem has caused me problems for three days.

Comment: All functions are build I just need the user to be able to to add tags to an input field associated with the image and wen the submit it calls the function already defined in the form I show above. if it helps to see what I mean I can give you a link to the site. My biggest problem with JS its I dont really understand the syntax so I am not sure what I am looking at or how to hack through it.

Comment: Please provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/240t5kyj/

Comment: when filed are uploaded Instead of showing the file names i need it to be input fields allowing the input of tags to go with each photo. So I assume if we could just move the file name to the name value of the input field they I could easily worth with that from there.

Comment: also if it helps, wuno.com/artistpit is the site. once you register and login to the dashboard you could use the photo upload and see what i'm talking about easily.